# Android 7 Chrome - play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio

I need the possibility to play a sound in the backend as soon as an order comes in. With Web Notifications a message is displayed and this is exactly where the sound should be played.
It works on desktop but not on Android 7.

On the Android device I already added the backend as home screen. The Android device is a SUNMI V2.

```
<audio id="notifiction_sound" src="/sounds/alarm.mp3" loop preload="auto" muted></audio>
```

This Function will be called after Web Notification is fired

```
window.ringSound = () =>
{
    let soundElem = document.getElementById('notifiction_sound');

    soundElem.muted = false;
    soundElem.pause();
    soundElem.currentTime = 0;
    window.waitFor(1000);
    soundElem.play();
};
```

Do somebody knows an workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is currently no working solution for this problem when using the latest versions of Chrome / Firefox Mobile. 
Therefore all devices that are affected by this will be equipped with Opera Mobile. Because here it still works